# ForeignKey and ManyToMany without db relation

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a question - is it possible to create a model with some relations, but when syncing database through manage.py syncdb not to create database relations? Just for example to have many-to-many tables and handle it through django ORM but without db foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, you could of course implement your own database `Field` which stores an integer pointing to the specific record. This could then used to lookup a model for that type, but you throw away all the checking a database does for you.

Is there any specific reason why you want this?

Comment: Data comes form different service and I need to synchronize it by cronjobs, so there'll be situations during data synch when relations won't be consistent.

Comment: I have something like ugly workaround for this -> specify in database configuration in settings.py 
'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0'}